# Does it matter if faces are slightly distorted for OpenCV Face Detection & Recognition?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, raspberry-pi4

I am writing a program using OpenCV face detection & recognition, using [this](https://www.superdatascience.com/blogs/opencv-face-recognition) as a guide

Does it matter if faces are distorted? As in, I'm thinking of placing camera* over a peephole in a door and there is intrinsic distortion in that. Will OpenCV still be able to detect & recognise?

System: Raspberry Pi 4 OS

Python Version: 3.x

*PS: If anyone can recommend a good RPi camera which would work well over a peephole that would be great. Thinking of RPi V2 Camera currently.

**Thanks! :-)**

Comment: Your question seems not clear. What do you mean by saying *good RPi camera*? What are your requirements? Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk By 'good' I mean 'most appropriate to the task'. At any rate, that was just a additional question to the actual question on Distortion

Comment: Does anyone know?!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the camera quality is not so important to detect face(or other objects) because I worked with worse(low resolution like 0.5 Mpx) cameras even on these cameras the results are fine. The main point about detecting objects depends on the algorithm you used. The popular algorithms:

1. Haar Cascade Face Detector in OpenCV
2. Deep Learning based Face Detector in OpenCV
3. HoG Face Detector in Dlib
4. Deep Learning based Face Detector in Dlib

According to documentation you shared, Haar Cascade is the algorithm which you are thinking to use. Haar Cascade can work faster but there can be some problems also(like occlusion, problem with many faces, and some distorted face images ets.) There is a very good documentation about the comparison of these algorithms in [this link](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88HdqNDQsEk) is also a tutorial about haar cascade face detection.

I don't think using peophole camera will be a problem to detect faces.

Comment: Right. On the blog, the programmer used LBP classifier as opposed to Haar. Do you have an idea on comparative rates?

Comment: Yes as document said OpenCV DNN seems better.

Comment: OK so LBP and DNN classifiers are the same?